# Is it possible to get root permission using Magisk in Work Profile?

Tags: root-access, 9.0-pie, magisk

I had flashed Magisk in the recovery, but when I run Magisk Manager in Work Profile it says Magisk is not installed. Does this imply that there is an independent recovery for Work Profile as well? Is there any way to gain root access in Work Profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose `User-independent` option in `Multiuser Mode` Settings of Magisk app.

User profiles and multi users are managed inside OS, nothing to do with recovery.

Comment: I have the same issues and I selected the "User-Independent" settings in Magisk Manager outside the work profile. After that the magisk app in my work profile ask for additional setup and downloads Magisk setup zip but after download it says "Setup Failed".

Comment: @SleepyLord If a feature doesn't work as expected, it's a bug. Register your issue [here](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/issues).